# turtlebot gmapping large area

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, create, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried unsuccessfully to map a large area using gmapping.  The map creation was working, and yesterday I created smaller maps.  However, today, after about 45 minutes of driving, the Turtlebot stops and I get the errors in the gmapping output: "could not get robot pose".  Also, I noticed that the create power LED is off, and in one case I got a power error on the dashboard.  The battery display showed that there was plenty of power.

Then, I turned the create back on and the robot briefly found it's pose. I started driving again, and the robot jumped off the map and I got the "out of bounds" errors in gmapping.  It seems it wasn't able to recover from that first stop.

I was trying to map a rectangular hallway area in an office building. The long edge is about 60 meters, and about 30 meters on the short edge.  I went around about 2 and 2/3 times trying to get the loop to close when the Create stopped.  So, I estimate that it traveled about 500 meters.

Do the Create's motors get hot and cause the create to shutdown?  What conditions would cause a power off?  Any insight into the practical run-time of the Turtlebot would be appreciated.

Incidentally, after the first time this happened, I changed the map resolution to 10cm, in case it was running out of map space.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27666/turtlebot-gmapping-large-area/) by [ceverett](https://answers.ros.org/users/1761/ceverett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 332 on 2012-02-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ceverett](https://answers.ros.org/users/1761/ceverett/) on 2012-02-17**:
Thank you.  I was able to get each hallway in separate runs, but I never got the whole floor in a single run without costmap "out of bounds" errors or the Create powering itself off (I am still investigating why that happens).  I merged the maps as you suggested (using Gimp) and was able to load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although this isn't a direct solution to the root cause of your issue (`Create`'s power down), making multiple sub-maps separately for a large area and [combining later by graphic editor](http://answers.ros.org/question/11641/manually-editing-maps) is a valid work-around for the completion.

In my case with `turtlebot`, after a long-run of `gmapping` (say an hour or so) the map tends to get corrupted (I see it via `RViz`), which made me split the large area into pieces. As long as the maps share the common "interfaces" b/w each other, combining shouldn't be a problem (although I got small pitfalls in editing `.pgm` files, that's another subject).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2012-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0